# How to save an animation with python-gnuplot?

Tags: python-2.7, gnuplot

I've been trying to save an animation with python-gnuplot.
I have tried the g.hardcopy command but the browser can't display the .gif image that is saved.

Is there any other command I could use?
I am using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with python-gnuplot, but it seems that `.hardcopy` just saves the last plot to file, and there's no special command for animations.

Animations are a sequence of independent plots, hence the pure gnuplot code is:

```
set terminal gif animate delay 100
set output "myAni.gif"
plot ...
plot ...
plot ...
...
unset output
```

Each plot command will generate a single frame, which will be displayed for 1 second (The unit of `delay` 0.01s, our value is 100, 0.01s*100=1s)

This translates to python-gnuplot like this:

```
g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
g('set terminal gif animate delay 100')
g('set output "myAni.gif"')
g.plot(...)
g.plot(...)
g.plot(...)
...
g('unset output')
```

Comment: Hello,
thanks for the input. I will see if I can save it as an .avi.

Cheers!

Comment: No, avi is not supported, only gif. If you want an avi, save each frame separately,  and use a video tool like ffmpeg to create a video.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i did.
Cheers.